# How to put divs in grid format, even when content size differs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner in web development and while building my website I came across a problem.

It turns out that I want to put the content of the blog of my site, in a format responsive grid, that is depending on the size of the screen, stay with 1, 2 or 3 columns.

The problem occurs when the contents of each div have different size and because of this appear layout failures, as you can see in the following image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoCYo.png)

I am leaving the page link to have access to the source code.
URL: https://www.vicioanimes.com/blog/

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using Bootstrap grid system in your web application. 
Bootstrap is mostly used to make responsive and mobile friendly websites.
Many links are easily available online, where you can learn bootstrap quickly.